# The exact values of Dehn functions

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely presented group having Dehn function of type $n^d$ for some natural number $d$. Is it possible to say that $G$ has a presentation the corresponding Dehn function in which is a polynomial of degree $d$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Dehn function of type $n^d$"? Do you mean $O(n^d)$ or $\Theta(n^d)$? Since there are groups with Dehn functions strictly between $n^d$ and $n^{d+1}$ for all $d \ge 2$, it seems feasible that you could have a Dehn function like $\lambda d^3 + \mu d^{5/2} + \cdots$.

Comment: I think the OP's hypothesis means: for some (and hence every) choice of presentation, the Dehn function is bounded above and below by polynomials of degree $d$ and positive leading coefficients.

Comment: ... If a group has a presentation for which Dehn equals $an^3+bn^{5/2}+o(n^{5/2})$, I don't see any reason why it could not have any other presentation for which the Dehn function is exactly a polynomial of degree 3.

Comment: I am interested to know, if there exists a non-trivial example of a f.p group whose Dehn function is explicitly computed. For example, is there a non-trivial known hyperbolic group such that for some finite presentation $\delta(n)=An+B$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by non-trivial? Do you regard free groups as trivial? They have Dehn function $0$ (on a free generating set).

Comment: Derek Holt: Yes I mean free groups or free Abelian groups as the trivial cases.

Comment: It would be easy for $\langle a,b \mid a^2=b^2=1 \rangle$, so maybe you should exclude virtually free groups! I would guess that this should be possible for surface groups, although I don't know whether anyone would have taken the trouble to calculate it exactly! What is the motivation?

Comment: In virtually free groups as well as surface groups, we know the Dehn function only up to equivalence. For example let $G$ be the fundamental group of a compact oreintable surface $M$. Let $\delta_0$ be Dehn function of $M$. Then for any finite presentation of $G$, the corresponding Dehn function is equivalent to $\delta_0$, i.e. there are two positive constants $A$ and $B$ such that $\delta(n)\leq A\delta_0(An)+An$ and  $\delta_0(n)\leq B\delta(Bn)+Bn$. This means that if $\delta_0$ is linear, then the diagram of $\delta$ lies between to lines.

Comment: This is the only knowledge we have about Dehn function of $G$. My motivation for this question was a wrong proof: I proved that if a sequence of f.p groups with polynomial Dehn functions converges to a hyperbolic group, then almost all terms are hyperbolic too. The proof was wrong because I was supposed that  all terms have Dehn functions which are really polynomials.